# ¿Como puedo hacer aparecer un dialogo al pulsar sobre un elemento de un menu?

Tags: android

Quiero hacer que me aparezca un dialogo al pulsar sobre un elemento de un menú, tengo una actividad que hace lo siguiente:

```
...
 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_item_activity, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.eliminar) {
        eliminar();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void eliminar(){

    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.add(android.R.id.content, new FragmentEliminarDialogo());
    ft.commit();


}

}
```

Contenido de `FragmentEliminarDialogo.java`

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;



@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class FragmentEliminarDialogo extends PreferenceFragment {

public FragmentEliminarDialogo() {
    // Constructor Por Defecto
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.dialog);
}


}
```

Contenido de `dialog XML`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <com.my.personal.project.MyDialogPreference
    android:key="dialog"
    android:title="pref_delete_dialog"
    android:dialogMessage="dialog_text"
    android:negativeButtonText="no"
    android:positiveButtonText="popup_button_yes"/>


</PreferenceScreen>
```

Y por ultimo el contenido de MyDialogPreference.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.preference.DialogPreference;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.io.File;

public class MyDialogPreference extends DialogPreference {

public MyDialogPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}

@Override
protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
    super.onDialogClosed(positiveResult);

    persistBoolean(positiveResult);//Esto devuelve si en el dialogo pulsaron aceptar o cancelar (Booleano)

    if (positiveResult) {

    }
}
}
```

El problema que tengo es que quiero que salga directamente el dialogo

Comment: El dialogo se abre si haces clic en que texto, pref_delete_dialog?

Comment: Si, solamente si hago click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recuerda que tu dialogo debe extender de [`DialogFragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) o [`DialogPreference`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/DialogPreference.html)

```
public class miFragmentDialog extends DialogFragment {
```

noto que tienes:

```
public class FragmentEliminarDialogo extends PreferenceFragment {
```

ya que tu lo estas llamando `FragmentEliminarDialogo` al llamar el metodo `eliminar()` :

```
public void eliminar(){
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.add(android.R.id.content, new FragmentEliminarDialogo());
    ft.commit();
}
```

Cambia tu funcion `eliminar()` para que abra una instancia de `MyDialogPreference()` :

```
   public void eliminar(){
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        MyDialogPreference myDialog = new MyDialogPreference();
        myDialog.show(fm, null);
 }
```

He encontrado la forma de hacerlo directamente desde el código

```
 AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Borrar")
            .setMessage("¿Seguro que quieres borrar este elemento?")
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // continue with delete
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // do nothing
                }
            })
            .show();
```

Comment: No puede resolver el método show

Comment: El problema es que usas un DialogPreference, permiteme buscar una manera de abrir programaticamente este Dialog.

Comment: @PelayoRodriguez pues al parecer esa es la única forma, crear otro diálogo. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805896/how-to-open-or-simulate-a-click-on-an-android-preference-created-with-xml-prog en esta pregunta, la respuesta es en realidad incorrecta, porque no hay método para abrir programáticamente un DialogPreference.